# UILabel (as an outlet) remains nil when accessing it from another controller (popup window)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

There are 2 controllers.
[this is how the UI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCN18.png)
[this is how I am creating the popup i.e. using segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpTD7.png)

HomeViewController:
has a label and a button. upon click on this button named --> 'add action' --> a popup is opened.

PopupViewController:
is a popup where user can enter input and tap save. in the popup, there is a textfield. User fills the field and clicks save.
upon save --> an IBAction is called for this PopupViewController, which has dismiss() function to dismiss the popup. 
and the completion block inside the dismiss function is where I am trying to instantiate HomeViewController to update the labels.
(Note: PopupViewController is created via segue, by selecting over the current context)

but while doing so, I see that, all the IBOutlets inside of HomeViewController are nil upon trying to save from popup, therefore I am not able to update the labels.

What I have tried:
I have checked other Q&A on web and verified below:
1. I have checked the connection of the label to the story board. it's correct.
2. I have used instantiateViewController syntax in order to instantiate 
HomeViewController properly.
but still the problem persist.

HomeViewController

```
var actionNames = [String]()
var actionDescriptions = [String]()
@IBOutlet weak var firstActionLabel: UILabel!

func updateViewWithNewAction() {
    print("updating views started")
    if firstActionLabel != nil {
        if actionNames.count > 0 {
            firstActionLabel.text = actionNames[0]
        } else {
            print("no actions in the array")
        }
    } else {
        print("firstActionLabel is nil")
    }
    print("updating views completed")
}

func addActions(actionName: String, actionDescription: String) {
    actionNames.append(actionName)
    actionDescriptions.append(actionDescription)
    print("actions added")
}
```

PopupViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var actionTitle: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var actionDescriptionTextView: UITextView!
@IBAction func createAction(_ sender: Any) {
    //getting action values from user
    actionName = actionTitle.text!
    actionDescription = actionDescriptionTextView.text!

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block started ---")
        let homeVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

        homeVC.addActions(actionName: self.actionName, actionDescription: self.actionDescription)
        homeVC.updateViewWithNewAction()
        print("completion block ended ---")
    })
}
```

Expected Result: upon createAction() of PopupViewController, the label inside HomeViewController should be updated with the new value.
Actual Result: firstActionLabel is nil, during homeVC.updateViewWithNewAction()

Comment: Are you sure, you want to instantiate a new HomeViewController on dismiss from the PopupViewController?

Comment: I am open to change it. Is there any other way to update label inside HomeViewController? for my case.

Comment: Can you show us the code, where you present the popup?

Comment: You have to implement the protocol delegate!! you can't instantiate HomeViewController because it's already instantiated and at the time of dismissing you instantiate new HomeViewController that's why you can't see updated labels.

Comment: @d4Rk I have added image to show where I show pop up. It's not through code, it's through segue. and selection 'over current context'

Comment: You can also access the presenting controller `presentingController as! HomeViewController`. Although a cleane solution would be to create a closure handler `onConfirmedActions: ((...) -> Void)?`, set that before presenting the controller and calling that on confirmation to pass the actions. However, you should also wrap your action into a struct (name & description as one object), that will save you problems with handling two arrays.

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav OK. can you help me more with that - if possible.

Comment: @Sulthan problem persists with use of `presentingController as! HomeViewController` too. I will need to learn about closure handler.. so will get back on that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I think you want something like this:

add in `HomeViewController`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let popupViewController = segue.destination as? PopupViewController {
        popupViewController.callback = self.addActions
    }
}
```

And in `PopupViewController` add

```
var callback: ((String, String) -> Void)?
```

Then in `PopupViewController` change

```
@IBAction func createAction(_ sender: Any) {
    //getting action values from user
    actionName = actionTitle.text!
    actionDescription = actionDescriptionTextView.text!

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        callback?(self.actionName, self.actionDescription)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was a great help to me. :) 

It works now. I want to upvote your answer but too less rep at my side so.

I updated PopupViewController like this:
 

    `var addActions: ((String, String) -> Void)?
    var updateView: (() -> Void )?
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            print("completion block started ---")
            self.addActions?(self.actionName, self.actionDescription)
            self.updateView?()
            print("completion block ended ---")
        })`
and HomeViewController like this with proper prepare statement as mentioned by you.

Comment: Glad to hear, that I could help you! I think you can anyway accept the answer :-)

Comment: Oh Yes. Just did it.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewcontroller {

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateViewWithNewAction() 
    }
```

The problem is, until `viewDidLoad`, any of you `IBOutlet` won't be initialized. They are supposed to initialize in via storyboard. You cannot get any reference until `viewDidLoad`.

If you don't want to call `updateViewWithNewAction()` every time, then add a `Bool` flag to decide to call or not call `updateViewWithNewAction()`. Whenever needed set the `Bool` flag from `PopUpViewController` or any other places.

Comment: I think a quite bigger problem is, that instead of delegating the actions (whatever) back to HomeViewController, he instantiates a new HomeVC ;-)

Comment: @Ratul, that is not the problem. I am already doing that. and it doesnt matter in my case, as I am calling  updateViewWithNewAction() from PopupViewController anyway

Comment: If you are assuming something, then just ask @nayem, read the para in OP's question `but while doing so, I see that, all the IBOutlets inside of HomeViewController are nil upon trying to save from popup, therefore I am not able to update the labels.`

Comment: @d4Rk yes thats another problem, introducing delegate to communicate back to the view controller who presented it. But it depends, because this pop up may be opened from any other view controller, he may want to deliberately open the `HomeViewController` without prior, which is not posted in the question.

Comment: Possible, but very unlikely. I just prefer to do a root cause analysis, to really fix the problem instead of fighting the symptoms.

Comment: If reusing the components you are creating, then the case would be very likely.

Comment: Well, now you are only trying to justify your blunder. What is it likely that you want to initialize your controller object again and for what purpose? Clearly the question says ___'add action' --> a popup is opened___ that indicates the pop up was shown from the `HomeViewController` and on completion of the pop up he tried to pass data to the controller which presented this pop up.

Comment: Read the question and the answer clearly, i don't state any of this like opening `HomeViewController` from popup view controller. Even if opening another controller in the same manner OP can achieve the output (Depends on OP's app requirememt, which is not clearly stated). i'm not trying to justify my answer, dont know why are you feeling this way. I just wrote the part where the home vc opens the popup. My answer does not provide any information regarding the create action. So the point you are arguing @nayem, makes no sense here.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry if I've offended you earlier. But my intention was never nearly any argument at all. I was trying to point you to the underlying problem that was ___communication between two objects___. How the OP was trying to setup the communication isn't the way how we typically follow in iOS development. So I thought you might want to guide him how to address that in particular other than deviating to a complete different path.

Comment: Yes i pointed out that issue with d4RK in 4th comment, discussing that issue of communicating back to the presenter view controller. Which you are repeating the same comment in just previous one. OP has the full right to exploit the whole communication however it goes with the convention or not. By meaning of exploiting  there are several way to communicate between them (without using conventional patterns), it's up to him, we can show him the way, but the choice is OP's.